# on page load text color not change jquery

Tags: jquery, css, onload

hi today i create a html and jquery code for specfic class color change on page load . but its not work on my server . i check it to jsfiddle its working fine can any one explain whats wrong this is code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.Pending').css('color', 'red');
$('.Approved').css('color', 'green');
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Approved">Approved</span>
<span class="Pending">Pending</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code . place your code in [$(docuemnt).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.Pending').css('color', 'red');
    $('.Approved').css('color', 'green');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Approved">Approved</span>
<span class="Pending">Pending</span>
```